Can't quit python with ctrl+D on mac
As the title says, ctrl+D does nothing, but instead, it is strange that ctrl+Z does quit Python ("zsh: suspended"), but I'm using Mac, not Windows. How to fix this?

What leads you to believe that CTRL+D is what is supposed to work? Other guides indicate that CTRL+Z is the way to close Terminal in MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477709/terminate-python-in-terminal-control-c-just-printing-c-macos-10-12

@music2myear Ctrl+Z means suspending a process, but the process still lives in the memory. Ctrl+D means sending SIGHUP to the process, which signals that the repl process should "log out", i.e., end normally.

"Ctrl+Z" doesn't quit Python, it only suspends the process. Under the hood, it sends the SIGTSTP signal to the Python process. You can revive the process by running the fg or bg command.
"Ctrl+D" should quit Python, but you need to do so on an empty prompt line---a prompt line with no characters, including any blank characters.
